# mysql 2 table join unknown column

Tags: mysql, sql, join

How can I display a joined table while also selecting another specific column of information?

```
SELECT `PROP_STREET`, `PROP_PRICE`, `PROP_STATUS`, `AGT_FNAME`, `AGT_LNAME`, `PROP_STATUS`
FROM `property`, `agent`
WHERE property.PROP_AGENT = agent.AGT_FNAME && property.PROP_STATUS = SOLD;
```

As you can see above, I am also trying to display rows that are ONLY with the `PROP_STATUS = SOLD` but I get an error saying `Error 1054 Unknown column SOLD in WHERE clause`

Comment: You need to quote sold

Comment: @ssj3goku878 He means `WHERE property.PROP_AGENT = agent.AGT_FNAME && property.PROP_STATUS = 'SOLD';`

Comment: What if I would like to add SOLD and Leased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to add single quotes to the `SOLD` value.  You should also learn to use modern `join` syntax.  You don't need backticks around every identifier.  And, using table aliases makes the query both easier to write and to read:

```
SELECT PROP_STREET, PROP_PRICE, PROP_STATUS, AGT_FNAME, AGT_LNAME, PROP_STATUS
FROM property p JOIN
     agent a
     on p.PROP_AGENT = a.AGT_FNAME
WHERE p.PROP_STATUS = 'SOLD';
```

(I would use table aliases for the `from` clause, but I don't know where they go.)

Finally, I doubt you need `PROP_STATUS` twice in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: What if I would like to add SOLD and Leased?

Comment: @ssj3goku878 . . . You would change the `where` clause to `WHERE p.PROP_STATUS in ('SOLD', 'Leased')`.

Comment: like this? `WHERE property.PROP_AGENT = agent.AGT_FNAME && property.PROP_STATUS = ("SOLD", "Leased");`

gives me an error `operand should contain 1 column`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add quotes to `SOLD` field